# Returning errors to gsp page in Grails after checking for hasErrors and Validating

Tags: validation, grails, gsp

I'm building this web app that works with user profiles. A user edit a profile and if he enters wrong data, the profile shows the invalid fields in red and shows the message. Very simple scenario. But for some reasons it doesn't work the way I assumed. I might be missing something somewhere. Here is what I do in my controller.

As you can see in the code below, I create a new Profile, I bind the params to it using an include list to only bind those params that profile accepts, and then call hasErrors on the profile instance. In debug mode, I can see that myProfile has errors when the user enters something wrong, but when I get back to the editProfile page, it doesn't show what field has the error. my gsp form has the render error tag and also hasError for each field.

```
def update (){

   def myProfile = new Profile()
   dataBind(params, myProfile, include:[.....])

   if (myProfile.hasErrors()){ 
      respond myUser.errors, view: 'editProfile'             
      return
   } 
   else{
      redirect(action:"viewProfile")
   }
}
```

My gsp is something like this, I don't have access to my home computer right now to post the exact gsp page:

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${myUser}" field="name">
    <g:message error="${myUser.errors.getFieldErrors("name")}" />
</g:hasErrors>
```

Comment: Since it looks like you're doing an HTML request (not Ajax), I'd typically respond with myUser, not myUser.errors.  Then the gsp can do a <g:hasErrors bean="${myUser}" />.

Comment: when do we use respond, and when do we use redirect when hasErrors is true ? I can't understand what to do when hasErrors() is true and I want to stop the flow and show the errors in the gsp page. I know "return" stops the flow. but should I use respond or redirect ?

Comment: Also if I have two domain objects in one gsp page and both have errors, is there a way to show errors on both of them ? I believe respond doesn't access two domain instance, correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to pass the errors back, pass the entire object to your gsp. Assuming the bean you have in your gsp page is 'myUser', then this is what the render statement should be:

```
render view: 'editProfile', model: [myUser: myProfile]
```

Comment: I made some comments above on the other answer, any suggestion or advice ?

Comment: When hasErrors() is true, you render your view and pass the bean with the errors and then return.

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple beans with errors, just use `<g:hasErrors>`, this will check for any bean with errors.  You can read more about it in the Grails documentation: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/hasErrors.html

Comment: So that way I can send multiple domain objects to the view. That makes sense. I actually were following how the scaffolding was doing it. I generated the controller and view for my domain class and followed the code structure, that's why I wanted to use respond the same way scaffolding was doing.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `respond bean.errors`, the bean will be called based on class name, not variable name.

In your case, you need to access the bean in you gsp as `profile` like so:

```
//variable in controller
def myProfile = new Profile()

//bean in views
<g:hasErrors bean="${profile}" field="name">
    <g:message error="${profile.errors.getFieldErrors("name")}" />
</g:hasErrors>
```

If you need to call your bean with a specific name like `myUser`, just pass it in the model:

```
render (view:'editProfile', model:[myUser: myProfile])
```